# Remapping hyphen to 'to' and 'through' in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

For some reason I am unable to make this work.

```
6-10
```

will natively it seems map to both

- 6-10
- 6 - 10
- 6 10

But I'd like it to map to:

- 6 to 10
- 6 through 10

In the case of #s

In the case of words I'd like a term I store as

```
Pre-history
```

to map to

- Pre-history
- Prehistory
- Pre history

I realize this might entail two different indexes but the first thing I'm trying to figure out is how to use wordforms to make this happen. So far no wordforms have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add following entries into wordforms file

```
Pre history => prehistory
prehistory => prehistory
```

This will make pre-history, pre history and prehistory work as same word. No need to add `pre-history => prehistory` as "-" is treated as space between.

Mapping 6-10 to 6 through 10 won't be possible currently in sphinx.

Comment: Actually all I ended up needing was prehistory > pre-history. This way sphinx natively handles pre-history=pre history and then prehistory=pre-history